# How to apply back pressure to kafka producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, rate-limiting, backpressure

[Back pressure](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2012/05/apply-back-pressure-when-overloaded.html) can help by limiting the queue size, thereby maintaining a high throughput rate and good response times for jobs already in the queue.

In RabbitMQ it can be applied setting [Queue length limit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html).

How can it be done with Kafka ?

Can this be done by keeping Rate Limiter(TokenBucket) between kafka producer and broker, where the current bucket size and refill rate be set dynamically with values of rate of consumption ? Like a rest api in producer receiving from consumer the rate at which consumer is processing messages.

Answer (score 1):

Load is typically distributed amongst brokers, so back-pressure from the producer client-side may not be necessary.

But you can add [quotas](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas) per client to throttle their requests.